# How can I use the next non-null LEAD value in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to select the next non-null lead scenario_timestamp. I tried the following method but received an 'Invalid cast from BOOL to TIMESTAMP' error.

```
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E6S',
        CAST(
            CONCAT
            (
                CAST(date AS STRING),
                ' ',
                FORMAT_TIMESTAMP
                ('%H:%M:%E6S', cast(lead(scenario_timestamp is not null ) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC )  as timestamp
                  )
                )
            ) AS TIMESTAMP
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
SELECT
            date,
            name,
            CASE
                WHEN scenario_timestamp IS NOT NULL THEN scenario_timestamp
                ELSE FORMAT_TIMESTAMP (
                    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E6S',
                    CAST(
                        CONCAT (
                            CAST(date AS STRING),
                            ' ',
                            FORMAT_TIMESTAMP (
                                '%H:%M:%E6S',
                                CAST(
                                    (
                                        SELECT
                                            MIN(sub.scenario_timestamp)
                                        FROM
                                            dates_combine AS sub
                                        WHERE
                                            sub.date > main.date
                                            AND sub.scenario_timestamp IS NOT NULL
                                    ) AS TIMESTAMP
                                )
                            )
                        ) AS TIMESTAMP
                    )
                )
            END AS scenario_timestamp
        FROM
            dates_combine AS main
```

Answer (score 0):

`lead()` doesn't have the option to ignore nulls but other functions such as `first_value()`, `last_value()` and `nth_value()` do. The latter would be useful if you needed to count off a certain number of non-nulls beyond the first one. You need to specify the `ignore nulls` option (inside parens) and then define the window as starting with the subsequent row so it won't begin the search from the top of the results:

```
first_value(scenario_timestamp ignore nulls) 
    over (order by date desc rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#first_value

If that function isn't available to you might have to use a method like this:

```
with data as (
    select *,
       -- sort opposite so that nulls get associated with the next non-null
       count(scenario_timestamp) over (order by date asc) as grp
    from dates_combine
)
select *,
    min(scenario_timestamp) over (partition by grp) as next_scenario_timestamp
from data;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/3kExJ964 (SQL Server example)

Related question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/123008/sql-bigquery-function-to-return-the-previous-non-null-value